# What type of company/business can be registered with one person?

Tags: united-states, small-business, limited-liability-company, start-up, private-company

In some countries, a company must at least has 2 board members to be registered. What about the US? What type of companies can be registered with only 1 person in the US?

EDIT: My interest is a S-Corp company which I think is a subtype of LLC. But I am not sure if it is possible to register a S-Corp with only one member?

Comment: There are different types depending on whether you're interested in liability, tax treatment, etc. A sole proprietorship is the simplest but you can also have single-member LLCs and corporations. Voting to close as "needs focus".

Answer (score 1):

a one member sole proprietorship (LLC) Limited Liability Company can be registered in the US.
[Reference](https://www.usa-corporate.com/start-us-company-non-resident/entity-types/)

Comment: Can I tax one member sole proprietorship (LLC) as a S-Corp?

Comment: @WDR, yes, you can.

Comment: (@gaefan) But it's not the default; to 'elect' S-corp status you must file form 2553 by the third month of the tax year it will be effective (which is at least a year before you file the _return_ for that year) unless you can prove reasonable cause for missing the deadline.